# scanf_s() dosen't return every input

Tags: c, console-application

i have writen some C code to read two Numbers and one Operator:

```
int Numberone = 0, Numbertwo = 0;
char Op;
scanf_s("%d %c %d", &Numberone, &Op, &Numbertwo);
```

After the user entered his Input (5 + 2) the variables have the followeing value: Numberone = 5, Op = + and  Numbertwo = 0. But that is wrong. Number two shall be 2. How can I improve my code? And why is my code wrong?

Comment: What __exactly__ is your input, and what _exactly is your __actual__ output and what __exactly__ is your expected output. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: `scanf_s()` (the microsoft one) expects a buffer size for `%c`. Just don't use it, use `scanf()`.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d %c %d", &Numberone, &Op, &Numbertwo);` --> `scanf_s("%d %c %d", &Numberone, &Op, 1, &Numbertwo);`. See [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Comment: btw, for actual user-input, `scanf()` and friends is the wrong choice anyways (but `sscanf()` on a line of input you got from `fgets()` could be fine). See my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `scanf_s` (note the `_s`), which requires a maximum length parameter for every parameter of type `%s` or `%c` (cf, for example, [scanf_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) at cppreference.com):

> `scanf_s`: Same as `scanf`, except that `%c`, `%s`, and `%[`
>   conversion specifiers each expect two arguments (the usual pointer and
>   a value of type `rsize_t` indicating the size of the receiving array,
>   which may be `1` when reading with a `%c` into a single char).

So you have too few parameters for your `%c` format, and it should be something like:

```
scanf_s("%d %c %d", &Numberone, &Op, (rsize_t) 1, &Numbertwo);
```

Comment: This describes the standard version of `scanf_s()` while my crystal ball suggests OP is using the MS function ... (very similar but unfortunately not exactly the same)

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use `scanf_s()`. Microsoft's compiler is telling you to use it, but it's really best to ignore this. While `scanf_s()` was designed to be "more secure" by requiring buffer sizes for `c`, `s` and `[` conversions, it was a proprietary Microsoft extension, so using it, you're **locked in** to Microsoft compilers. Your actual problem is that you don't pass a buffer size in your call, `scanf_s()` assumes that `&Numbertwo` is the buffer length.

The situation is even worse since the C standard also includes a `scanf_s()`. The standard version expects the buffer size to be given as an **element count** as an `rsize_t`, while the Microsoft version expects a **byte count** as an `unsigned`, so they are subtly incompatible! IMHO, this whole function is unnecessary anyways, just using field widths allows you to write secure code with plain `scanf()`.

Because `scanf()` isn't well-suited for recovering from parsing errors, you shouldn't use it directly for interactive input, instead read a whole line and parse that (for example with `sscanf()`). Your code could then look like this:

```
int Numberone = 0, Numbertwo = 0;
char Op;
char line[512];
if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
{
    // error reading ...
}
if (sscanf(line, "%d %c %d", &Numberone, &Op, &Numbertwo) != 3)
{
    // error parsing ...
}
```

handle errors accordingly.